# Selecting Random Results From JSON

Tags: php, arrays, json

I'm looking for some advice on how to structure what I'm trying to do.

I have a CURL request and I want to return random array items from the results

The JSON will contain entries like below

```
{
   "total_entries" : 5642,
   "jobs" : [
      {
         "location" : "Southampton",
         "agency" : {
            "type" : "Corporate",
            "url" : "https://www.example.com/employer",
            "title" : "Employer Name"
         },
         "posted" : "2023-07-11T01:12:49Z",
         "url" : "/j/123456789/JOB-TITLE",
         "hl_title" : "<em>JOB TITLE</em>",
         "type" : [
            "Permanent"
         ],
         "description" : "DESCRIPTION HERE",
         "id" : 123456789,
         "salary" : "\u00a311.25 - \u00a315.00/hour",
         "title" : "FULL JOB TITLE",
         "applications" : "<10"
      }]
}
```

I already have the default records being shown in the main result div showing 100 records,
however I have a side column and I want to show randomly picked 20 entries from the same feed

I can't figure out how to structure it so any help would be great.
If it were a mysql query I could simply use RAND() but thats not the case here